# Encrypting connectionStrings in classic ASP

Tags: encryption, asp-classic

I'm looking for a way to increase security on some older web apps. They currently have their connection strings saved in plain text in an `include.asp` file. Ideally I was thinking of moving these to a web.config file and encrypting this using `aspnet_regiis.exe`, but this does not work for Classic ASP.

I've had a look around the internet but cannot find anything that seems to fit this specifically, has anyone run into the same issue before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypting connection string in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337663/encrypting-connection-string-in-classic-asp)

Comment: You can store the connection string in "global.asa"...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867462/classic-asp-global-asa-sql-server-2008-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

The best way to protect your include.asp is to use anonymous authentication on the site and be sure to set the NTLM security of that file so that it can only be read by the user used by IIS.

If that is not possible you can obfuscate the string in a number of ways but almost none will be very secure, so you can avoid these strings being seen by the casual nosy user but not to a hacker.

- you can use your own crypt and decrypt function, but they will be visible themselves in the .asp files, see [here](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/vbscript-systems-administrator/very-simple-encryption-example-with-vbscript/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984710/is-there-a-method-to-encrypt-passwords-stored-in-a-vbs) for examples
- you can use an external crypt and encrypt tool that is run from your .asp like this (i use this to run a Ruby script and get the results, replace the command executed by yours)

  ```
  set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
  set objCmd = objWShell.Exec("cmd.exe /c c:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe d:\inetpub\site\appl\RMW\import\import.rb")
  result = objCmd.StdOut.Readall()
  errors = objCmd.STDERR.Readall() 
  set objCmd = nothing
  set objWShell = nothing
  ```
- You could use [Windows Script Encoder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/1d132da1-2014-4f34-87f5-d787e764995f/save-encrypted-password-in-vbscript?forum=ITCG) if your OS supports it, see